# How to signal a workflow programmatically

Tags: elsa-workflows

I am testing Elsa hosting in a console app (in production it will be a background job server). For various architectural reasons I want to restart suspended workflows manually, either from a blocking activity or by sending signals. In all of the sample code Web API calls are required, which I want to avoid. I was hoping to do something like this:

```
serviceHost.Services.GetRequiredService<IWorkflowInstanceExecutor>();
```

However the `ExecuteAsync()` method requires an activity Id and I can't find any other interface with a method to send a signal to a workflow.
Is there a specific interface for signalling?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, with a little help of the VS Object Browser. Just get the signaler service:

```
var signaler = serviceHost.Services.GetRequiredService<ISignaler>();
```

then call the `DispatchSignalAsync` method:

```
await signaler.DispatchSignalAsync(signal: "Approve", workflowInstanceId: workflowId);
```